# Not measurable function whose module is measurable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I read through my notes that is trivial to find a not measurable function $f$ whose module $|f|$ is  measurable. 
However I don't know how to provide such an example.

Comment: If $A$ is a non-measurable set, take $f=\chi_A-\chi_{A^C}$.

Comment: But if we take $\left(|\chi_A-\chi_{A^C}|\right)^{-1}\lbrace{1\rbrace}$ this is either $A$ or $A^C$ and $A$ is not measurable...

Comment: but still $A\cup A^C=X$ and the full space belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra. So it's done...am I right?